# 3 tables to refer at one

Tags: sql

I'm studying SQL, and I'm stuck with this project.

I need to create this script that creates 3 tables, and that they refer to the "Matricula" table.

I can't run the code, and I can't see my error either.

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

CREATE TABLE Classe 
(
    ClasseID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Nr_serie NUMBER(2)
    Sg_Turma VARCHAR2(2)
    Cd_Escola NUMBER(6)
    Cd_Grau NUMBER(2)
    Cd_Periodo NUMBER(2)

    PRIMARY KEY ClasseID
);

CREATE TABLE Matricula 
(
    MatriculaID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Matricula VARCHAR(255),
    Nr_Rgm NUMBER(8)
    Cd_Class NUMBER(8)
    Dt_Matricula DATE

    PRIMARY KEY (MatriculaID)
    FOREIGN KEY (ClasseID) REFERENCES Classe (ClasseID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AlunoID) REFERENCES Aluno (AlunoID)
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno 
(
    AlunoID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Nome VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    Nm_Name VARCHAR2(40)
    Nm_Father VARCHAR2(40)
    Nm_Mom VARCHAR2(40)
    Dt_Birth VARCHAR2(40)
    Id_Sex VARCHAR2(40)

    PRIMARY KEY AlunoID
);
```

Comment: We need to understand what database you are using to give you the correct answer because the syntax changes depending on which database you use. Is it SQL Server, Postgre, Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: If one of the answers answers your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order of table creation: When you create table `Matricula`, the table `Aluno` is not yet known, as the database processes the statements one by one.

Answer (score -1):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Classe]') AND TYPE in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE Classe (
ClasseID intEGER NOT NULL ,
Nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Nr_serie NUMBER(2)
Sg_Turma VARCHAR2(2)
Cd_Escola NUMBER(6)
Cd_Grau NUMBER(2)
Cd_Periodo NUMBER(2)
PRIMARY KEY ClasseID
);
END
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Classe]') AND TYPE in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
CREATE TABLE Matricula (
MatriculaID intEGER NOT NULL ,
Matricula varchar(255),
Nr_Rgm NUMBER(8)
Cd_Class NUMBER(8)
Dt_Matricula DATE
PRIMARY KEY (MatriculaID)
FOREIGN KEY (ClasseID) REFERENCES Classe (ClasseID),
FOREIGN KEY (AlunoID) REFERENCES Aluno (AlunoID)
);
END
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Classe]') AND TYPE in (N'U'))
        BEGIN
CREATE TABLE Aluno (
AlunoID integer NOT NULL ,
Nome varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
Nm_Name VARCHAR2(40)
Nm_Father VARCHAR2(40)
Nm_Mom VARCHAR2(40)
Dt_Birth VARCHAR2(40)
Id_Sex VARCHAR2(40)
PRIMARY KEY AlunoID
);
END
```

I THINK IF YOU EXECUTE THIS SCRIPT THEN TABLES CREATED PROPERLY